Who said: "The crucified Christ is our High Priest?"
An expression I heard during a September mass this year. Just wondering what is the source?

The whole letter to the Hebrews, eg Hebrew 9:11

Welcome to Christianity Stack Exchange. Interesting question, but shouldn't it be the resurrected Christ who is our High Priest?  Just a thought. You may like to take our Tour to help you with future questions: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour

Are you looking for a reference from a Catholic source or from the Bible?

The primary source is the Letter to the Hebrews, especially:

Hebrews 4
14Since then we have a great high priest who has passed through the heavens, Jesus, the Son of God, let us hold fast our confession. 15For we do not have a high priest who is unable to sympathize with our weaknesses, but one who in every respect has been tempted as we are, yet without sin.


Hebrews 9
11But when Christ appeared as a high priest of the good things that have come, then through the greater and more perfect tent (not made with hands, that is, not of this creation) 12he entered once for all into the holy places, not by means of the blood of goats and calves but by means of his own blood, thus securing an eternal redemption.

Also 2:17, 3:1, 5:5, 5:10, 6:20, 7:26, and 8:1.
See also What does it mean that Jesus is our High Priest?.

Was just about to do the same thing. Except I would have said "And then the following church fathers as well... Gregory Thaumaturgus, Dionysius the Great, Julius Africanus, Anatolius, Tertullian (IV), Minucius Felix, Commodian, the not saint Origen, Augustine... the list goes on."

@Wyrsa, if you want to propose an addition, go for it.

Nope, I was simply saying you beat me to it :)

@Wyrsa and Matthew.  It's a sad reflection on not enough catechism for Catholic youth, at least the mass text has it, so an adult Catholic can start by trying to understand it.  And lo and behold: Heb 4:12-16 and Heb 9:11-15 are included in the Catholic lectionary which is ironically MORE thorough than a typical evangelical church homily text for 3 years.  So if a Catholic just go to church for 3 years and the homily is good, they would have known the answer already.

@GratefulDisciple Um... okay?

Yes, Jesus is our High Priest.
Please take your Bible out and read the Bible's words.
After speaking about the Melchisedec priesthood and the sacrifice of Jesus Christ, the writer says, "We have such an high priest, who is set on the right hand of the throne of the Majesty in the heavens; A minister of the sanctuary, and of the true tabernacle, which the Lord pitched, and not man."  Hebrews 8:1.2.
Read all of the book of Hebrews and you will learn a lot about Jesus as our high priest.  He is not of the Old Covenant, but of the New.
Protestant Christians think they do not need a high priest.  In fact they do not have a priest at all. But you are used to priests.  You are right, we do need a priest.
If you read of the work of the Levitical priests and high priest in Leviticus, you will see a type of the heavenly, because it was made after the pattern in the heavens. This is repeated in Hebrews 8:5.6.  If the Old was made after the pattern, then a high priest was necessary.
Earthly priests also have their part to play.  The book of Hebrews is a comparison between the Old Covenant and the New Covenant. The writer shows that the Old Covenant was limited to the life of each man, and as we are all sinful, they had to offer sacrifices for themselves first, then they could serve the people.
But in the New Covenant, Jesus has no sin and therefore this covenant is better than the Old.  He made one sacrifice and He will never die again. This is also better.
Saying the covenant is better does not mean the old one was bad. It was just limited for a time.  But now we are under the New Covenant, which you would understand is salvational.
I could tell you in my words, but it would  be much better if you read God's words.  As I have suggested, read your Bible and you will read what God has said.   Others can do the same in their own words, but if you read the Bible you will know it is true. And you will know you have your answer.
And this is what you want -- the answer and the truth.

Welcome to Christianity Stack Exchange.  The questioner heard this expression at a Catholic mass and is looking for an answer from a Catholic perspective. This is also a reference request, although it isn't clear if a Biblical reference is what's being asked for.

@Lesley, I don't believe the OP is asking for a Scriptural reference specifically, however as the earliest reference would seem to be from Scripture (primarily, Hebrews), it's sort of a moot point.
